# Failed to register Azure Integration Runtime (self-hosted). The Authentication Key is invalid or empty

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating a self hosted integration runtime. There is error in registration after installed the IR on Window.The authentication key is just copied from portal and paste on it. But, the warning says the key is invalid or empty. How can I solve it?
Both Azure Data Factory and on-prem data server are on same time zone so no time delay.
Any suggestion would be great as struggled most of the day.
I have tried by using express route exe and integration runtime msi both but same result no luck :(
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the key you are using is not expired and also that you have installed the latest version of SHIR. If not , then kindly uninstall and reinstall .

Comment: It was networking issue as same key working on public endpoint network setting. Now it will fix private endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It was networking issue as same key working on public endpoint network setting. Now it will fix private endpoint.